# SQL Management Studio won't connect to TFS

Tags: tfs, ssms-2012, redgate

I am doing some research regarding continuous integration with SQL servers. I downloaded some free trials of Red-Gate to play around with. However, I am having trouble getting my SQL Server Management studio to connect to TFS. The error I'm getting is that the page is not found. [Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOQ68.png)

This is probably an incredibly easy fix, but I'm new to my job, so I'm a bit overwhelmed at the moment.

Comment: I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015, TFS 2015, and SSMS 2012.

Comment: In another error box, I am getting the TF31002 Error. This is only occurring in SQL Management Studio. I can connect to TFS just fine in VS 2015.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but this blog post describes how we handle automated deployments to SQL server - http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/

Comment: You want to open the TFS Database from Management Studio? What do you mean with 'getting my SQL Server Management Studio to connect to TFS'?

Comment: I assume you're using Redgate SQL Source Control? What version of TFS are use using?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can connect to TFS fine in VS2015. Then the settings of SQL with TFS should be no problem.

The most possibility should be the permission, make sure you have enough permission to open the TFS Database from SQL Management Studio.

Also you can check this link from MSDN [TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244143.aspx) to find a solution.